# Ubuntu: javac package gnu.io does not exist

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino, classpath, gnu

I am running on Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to communicate my Arduino with Java.

I have a source file SerialTest.java in directory /home/me/Desktop/folder

Inside the directory contains both RXTXcomm.jar, librxtxSerial.so, and my source code file.

I tried these methods to compile the SerialTest.java:

### `$ javac SerialTest.java`

and I get the following errors:

`SerialTest.java:4: error: package gnu.io does not exist`

### `$ javac -verbose -classpath .:RTXXcomm.jar SerialTest.java`

And I got the same error

`SerialTest.java:4: error: package gnu.io does not exist`

What I have referred to: [javac -classpath not doing the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876924/javac-classpath-not-doing-the-trick)

May I know what I am doing wrong? I am new to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your classpath option is wrong. It should be:

```
-classpath .:RTXXcomm.jar
```

Note the colon (`:`). The semicolon (`;`) is used as a command separator by the shell.

What happens currently is that this command is executed:

```
javac -verbose -classpath .
```

Hence the first error: "no source files". And then this command is passed:

```
RTXXcomm.jar SerialTest.java
```

Hence the second error: "RXTXcomm.jar: command not found."

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The code got compiled however i still get the

SerialTest.java:4: error: package gnu.io does not exist

error. May i know if there is anything that i left out? Thanks.

Comment: You also need to specify the classpath when running your command

Comment: Hi, this is the command that i typed

javac -verbose -classpath .:RTXXcomm.jar SerialTest.java

may i know if this is correct? I still get the error in which gnu.io does not exist. Thanks